# How to bind two keyboard keys like Ctrl +L in an input

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, textinput

I have one text input and one button (see below). How can I use JavaScript to trigger the button's click event when the some "Ctrl + Enter (other shortcut)" key is pressed?

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those keys have are stored differently in the event values so you can check if they are both pressed like so

```
if(event.keyCode == 13 && event.ctrlKey){
   //insert logic
}
```

Other keys can be accessed this way as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `keyCode` and `ctrlKey`:

```js
    function check(e) {
        tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if(tecla == 13 && e.ctrlKey)
            alert("hello");;
    }
```

```html
<input type="search"  onkeydown="return check(event);" id="txtSearch" />
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="doSomething();" />
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, You can do it like

```
<script>
 document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.which == 77) {
    alert("M key was pressed");
  } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.which == 66) {
    alert("Ctrl + B shortcut combination was pressed");
  } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.which == 89) {
    alert("Ctrl + Alt + Y shortcut combination was pressed");
  } else if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.shiftKey && e.which == 85) {
    alert("Ctrl + Alt + Shift + U shortcut combination was pressed");
  }
 };
</script>
```

Or you can use a library - https://wangchujiang.com/hotkeys/